# php second query from results of first query

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running bootstrap tabs and on the second tab I'd like to display all other products in that category (around 15 records), the below query returns 1 record that has the Category ID in it.

The category ID is available in the product but aren't sure how to write the second query to return those records.

I will echo it out similar to

```
echo "<p>Part #: " . $row["partNo"]. " - Name: " . $row["prodName"]. "</p>";
```

any help will be good.

**table structure**

tblProducts

- id
- partNo
- prodName
- categoryID_FK

tblCategories

- id
- catName

**products.php**

```
<?php include "db_conn.php"; ?>
<?php include "inc_products.php"; ?>  
    <div class="container">
      <h2><?php echo $prodName; ?></h2>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Details</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Categories</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <h3>Product # <?php echo $partNo; ?></h3>
          <p>Description: <?php echo $prodDesc; ?></p>
          <p>Category: <?php echo $catName; ?></p>
          <p>Cost: $<?php echo $unitPrice; ?></p>
          <p>Active: <?php echo ($discontinued == 0) ? "Yes" : "No"; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 1</h3>
          <?php echo $outp; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 2</h3>
          <p> </p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Menu 3</h3>
          <p> </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**inc_products.php**

```
<?php
  $partNoid = intval($_GET['partNo']);

  $query = "Select Distinct
        *
        From
        tblProducts Inner Join
        tblCategories On tblCategories.id = tblProducts.categoryID_FK Inner Join
        tblSuppliers On tblSuppliers.id = tblProducts.supplierID_FK Inner Join
        users On users.id = tblProducts.userID_FK
        Where partNo = $partNoid";
  $result = $conn->query($query);

  if($result === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $query . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  } else {
    $result->data_seek(0);

        if($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            $partNo = $rs["partNo"];
            $prodName = $rs["prodName"];
            $prodDesc = $rs["prodDesc"];
            $unitPrice = $rs["unitPrice"];
            $catName = $rs["catName"];
            $discontinued = $rs["discontinued"];
            $catID = $rs["categoryID_FK"];
        }
    }
  $result->free();

  $query2 = "Select
    *
    From
    tblProducts Inner Join
    tblCategories On tblCategories.id = tblProducts.categoryID_FK
    Where $partNoid AND tblProducts.categoryID_FK = $catID";
$result2 = $conn->query($query2);

if($result2 === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $query2 . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  } else {
    $result2->data_seek(0);

            while($rs2 = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                $outp .= $rs2["partNo"] ;
                $outp .= ' - '   . $rs2["prodName"] . '<br>';       
        }
    }
  $result2->free();
$conn->close();
```

?>

Comment: clarify your database structure and question please

Comment: how many records does the query return if you were to run that in a gui? Are you expecting more than one record - I ask because of the `if($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {` as opposed to `while( $rs=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: so use the same logic that you used for the first tab, *n'est-ce pas?*. You didn't give us much to go on here, except a query.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your original query, if you then want to get the category id from that row and select all other products of that category with a second query, try the following:

```
$secondQuery = "Select Distinct
        *
        From
        tblProducts Inner Join
        tblCategories On tblCategories.id = tblProducts.categoryID_FK
        Where partNo = $partNoid AND tblProducts.catName = $catName";

//this is the same query as before, but now with a filter for category

$allCategoryResults = $conn->query($secondQuery);

//Then just loop through the results, as suggested by RamRaider in the comments.

while($tmp = $allCategoryResults->fetch_assoc()){
    //do whatever with your results
}
```

Even better would be to use the category id in your query instead of the category name, but you can easily swap those out if you choose.

Comment: almost there, I'll post what I have now, problem is it is returning the same record over and over.

Comment: I updated my answer - I made a mistake -  try changing `fetch_array()` to `fetch_assoc()` in your while condition.

Comment: @James Don't forget to mark as an Accepted Answer with the green check mark up by the up and down arrows. If it solved your problem. That's how we roll on the stack.